# What is the difference between npm install and sudo npm install?

Tags: linux, typescript, ubuntu, npm, sudo

I am new to linux. I am trying to install typescript so I executed this command:
`npm i typescript`
The command completed without errors but when I typed `tsc --version` to verify the installation, I got the error
`-bash: /usr/bin/tsc: No such file or directory`.

I then tried to install typescript again but this time using the command `sudo npm i -g typescript`. The command completed successfully again but this time `tsc --version` worked as expected and returned the typescript compiler version number.

My question is:

- What is the difference between `npm i typescript` and `sudo npm i -g typescript`?
- Did the first command actually install anything? If yes, where? and why then did `tsc --version` fail?
- What happens with sudo and without sudo? when should I use sudo and when not?

Thanks!

Comment: The difference is: running `npm install` as a root user or not. This does not look related to programming to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-g` flag causes npm to [install a module globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#global) instead of in the current project. [It](https://code.mendhak.com/npm-install-globally-is-bad/) [isn't](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-you-should-stop-installing-npm-packages-globally-1b56b97b70cd) [recommended](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/issue-with-global-node-npm-packages/). You should probably use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) instead.

> Did the first command actually install anything? If yes, where? and why then did tsc --version fail?

In the `node_modules` directory for your current project, which isn't in your `$PATH` environment variable (which is why you should use `npx tsc --version` instead).

`sudo` is a program that [makes a command run as root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) instead of as your normal user. You might need it to install global modules if you are using a version of Node.js installed system wide (as opposed to a private one such as one managed by [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) because ordinary users don't have permission to write to the system-wide collection of installed modules.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for your reply. So in order for 'g' to work I need 'sudo', correct?

Comment: @Walid — Maybe. Maybe not. That's why the last sentence of this answer says **might**.